# Precalculus Word Problem: setting up linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

This is a math question, I got $18 I wonder if anyone can get the same answer and explain how.

Beatrice went shopping with #120. She bought items in five stores. In each store she spent `$3` more than the previous. She went home with `$25`. How much did she spend in the first store?

Comment: I think in your solution, you're forgetting about the 25 dollars she's supposed to have left. If you call $x$ the amount of money she spent at the first store, how much did she spend at each of the others?

Comment: $x+x+3+x+6+x+9+x+12=5x+30$. This is what she's spent in the stores, x being the amount spent in the first store. $120-5x-30=25$. This is how much she still has. That is, the equation to be solved is $5x=95$. From where   $x= ...$???

Answer (score 4):

Let $x$ be how much she spent in the first store:
$$ \begin{align}
  (x) + (x+3) + (x+6) + (x+9) + (x+12) + 25 &= 120 \\
  5x + 55 &= 120 \\
  5x &= 65 \\
  x &= 13 
\end{align} $$

Comment: Where does the 55 in `5x + 55 = 120` come from?

Comment: The constants $c$ in the expressions $(x+c)$ are being added up and then summed with $25$.

Answer (score 0):

Another method :

Let $\left(u_n\right)_{n\geq1} \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence where $u_n$ is the money she spent in the $n$th store.

$$u_{n+1}=u_n+3^\implies\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_n=u_0+3n$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n u_k=(n+1)\frac{2u_0+3n}{2}$$
$$\implies u_0=\frac{2\sum_{k=0}^n u_k-3n(n+1)}{2(n+1)}$$

She comes homes with \$25 so $\sum_{k=0}^4 u_k = 120-25 = 95$.

Hence :

$$u_0 = \frac{2 \cdot 95-3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5}{2\cdot5}=13$$

So she spent \$13 in the first store.